# classList.add Как выбрать все элементы?

Tags: javascript, html

Привет всем.

Как можно выбрать все classList.add?

Проблема в том что если наш DIV Дублируется то JS выдает ошибку.

Вот рабочий пример скрипта. https://jsfiddle.net/pkgzwct6/50/

```
<div id="test1">9</div>
<div id="test2">10</div>
<div id="test3">11</div>
<div id="test4">12</div>
<div id="test5">13</div>
<div id="test6">14</div>
<div id="test7">15</div>
<div id="test8">16</div>
<div id="test9">17</div>
<div id="test">test</div>
```

и сам JS.

```
const block1 = test1;
const block2 = test2;
const block3 = test3;
const block4 = test4;
const block5 = test5;
const block6 = test6;
const block7 = test7;
const block8 = test8;
const block9 = test9;
const block = test;
calculate_timeout = seconds => {
  now = new Date(), next = new Date();
  next.setSeconds(seconds);
  if(next.getTime() <= now.getTime())
    next.setMinutes(next.getMinutes()+1);
  return next.getTime() - now.getTime();
}
(function timer_callback() {
  let now = new Date;
  if(now.getHours() >= 06 && now.getHours() < 09){
    block.classList.add('now');
    block9.classList.remove('now');
  }
   if(now.getHours() >= 09 && now.getHours() < 10){
    block.classList.remove('now');
    block1.classList.add('now');
  }
  if(now.getHours() >= 10 && now.getHours() < 11){
    block1.classList.remove('now');
    block2.classList.add('now');
  }
    if(now.getHours() >= 11 && now.getHours() < 12){
    block2.classList.remove('now');
    block3.classList.add('now');
  } 
  if(now.getHours() >= 12 && now.getHours() < 13){
    block3.classList.remove('now');
    block4.classList.add('now');
  }
  if(now.getHours() >= 13 && now.getHours() < 14){
    block5.classList.remove('now');
    block6.classList.add('now');
  }
  if(now.getHours() >= 14 && now.getHours() < 15){
    block6.classList.remove('now');
    block7.classList.add('now');
  }
  if(now.getHours() >= 15 && now.getHours() < 16){
    block7.classList.remove('now');
    block8.classList.add('now');
  }
   if(now.getHours() >= 01 && now.getHours() < 23){
    block8.classList.remove('now');
    block9.classList.add('now');
  }

})();
```

CSS.

```
#test.now{
  background: green;
}
#test{
  background: red;
}
#test1.now{background: green;}
#test1 {background: red;}
#test2.now{background: green;}
#test2 {background: red;}
#test3.now{background: green;}
#test3 {background: red;}
#test4.now{background: green;}
#test4 {background: red;}
#test5.now{background: green;}
#test5 {background: red;}
#test6.now{background: green;}
#test6 {background: red;}
#test7.now{background: green;}
#test7 {background: red;}
#test8.now{background: green;}
#test8 {background: red;}
#test9.now{background: green;}
#test9 {background: red;}
```

Если теперь добавим еще один элемент DIV

Пример

```
<div id="test9">17</div>
<div id="test9">17</div>
```

То сразу выдает ошибку JS. Вот ссылка На код с Ошибкой. `[https://jsfiddle.net/pkgzwct6/51/][2]`

Помогите разобраться...

Comment: "выбрать все classList.add" ??

Comment: я бы советовал id делать уникальным на странице иначе, я вообще не понимаю, зачем оно надо...

Comment: он должен выбрать все по функции

Comment: Не могу сделать уникальный это слайдер....

Comment: код выдает ошибку из-за того что  const block9 = test9; ета вот строка предполагает наличие уникального id

Comment: Изначально был Var. Но это тоже не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно получится как-то так ?

```js
const block1 = document.getElementsByClassName('test1')[0];
const block2 = document.getElementsByClassName('test2')[0];
const block3 = document.getElementsByClassName('test3')[0];
const block4 = document.getElementsByClassName('test4')[0];
const block5 = document.getElementsByClassName('test5')[0];
const block6 = document.getElementsByClassName('test6')[0];
const block7 = document.getElementsByClassName('test7')[0];
const block8 = document.getElementsByClassName('test8')[0];
const block9 = document.getElementsByClassName('test9');
const block = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];
calculate_timeout = seconds => {
    now = new Date(), next = new Date();
    next.setSeconds(seconds);
    if (next.getTime() <= now.getTime())
      next.setMinutes(next.getMinutes() + 1);
    return next.getTime() - now.getTime();
  }
  (function timer_callback() {
    let now = new Date;
    if (now.getHours() >= 06 && now.getHours() < 09) {
      block.classList.add('now');
      block9.classList.remove('now');
    }
    if (now.getHours() >= 09 && now.getHours() < 10) {
      block.classList.remove('now');
      block1.classList.add('now');
    }
    if (now.getHours() >= 10 && now.getHours() < 11) {
      block1.classList.remove('now');
      block2.classList.add('now');
    }
    if (now.getHours() >= 11 && now.getHours() < 12) {
      block2.classList.remove('now');
      block3.classList.add('now');
    }
    if (now.getHours() >= 12 && now.getHours() < 13) {
      block3.classList.remove('now');
      block4.classList.add('now');
    }
    if (now.getHours() >= 13 && now.getHours() < 14) {
      block5.classList.remove('now');
      block6.classList.add('now');
    }
    if (now.getHours() >= 14 && now.getHours() < 15) {
      block6.classList.remove('now');
      block7.classList.add('now');
    }
    if (now.getHours() >= 15 && now.getHours() < 16) {
      block7.classList.remove('now');
      block8.classList.add('now');
    }
    if (now.getHours() >= 01 && now.getHours() < 23) {
      block8.classList.remove('now');
      for(var i = 0; i < block9.length; i++){
     block9[i].classList.add('now');
      }  
    }

  })();
```

```css
.test.now {
  background: green;
}

.test {
  background: red;
}

.test1.now {
  background: green;
}

.test1 {
  background: red;
}

.test2.now {
  background: green;
}

.test2 {
  background: red;
}

.test3.now {
  background: green;
}

.test3 {
  background: red;
}

.test4.now {
  background: green;
}

.test4 {
  background: red;
}

.test5.now {
  background: green;
}

.test5 {
  background: red;
}

.test6.now {
  background: green;
}

.test6 {
  background: red;
}

.test7.now {
  background: green;
}

.test7 {
  background: red;
}

.test8.now {
  background: green;
}

.test8 {
  background: red;
}

.test9.now {
  background: green;
}

.test9 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">9</div>
<div class="test2">10</div>
<div class="test3">11</div>
<div class="test4">12</div>
<div class="test5">13</div>
<div class="test6">14</div>
<div class="test7">15</div>
<div class="test8">16</div>
<div class="test9">17</div>
<div class="test9">17</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
```

Comment: но а как его заставить срабатывать сразу на все элементы ?

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, что именно вам надо, можно плиз больше подробностей ? 
Вам нужно чтобы все дивы в данном примере меняли цвет ?

Comment: Нет. В твоем примере он выделяет только первый Див. 

а мне нужно что-бы он выделил все дивы с классом test9

Comment: посмотрите мой пример еще раз, я там вносил правки 15 мин назад, чтобы он выделял все дивы с классом test9